# Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin dynamically apache (regex)

Tags: regex, apache

I want to allow cross domain request for several servers following this pattern:

```
https://en.example.com, https://de.example.com
```

It seems rather simple but I'm not good with regexes and don't know how to try them without shutting down the server itself. I have tried this one but it doesn't work.

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?example.com$"
```

Comment: You forgot to escape the last dot as well.

Comment: Have a look at what values are allowed for [*Access-Control-Allow-Origin*](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header). Hint: it’s not a regular expression.

Comment: @hwnd Didn't work neither but thanks for help. Is it possible that the url I use `example.com` is not the real one like behind a proxy or something?

Comment: @Gumbo I took a look but honnestly I don't see how is it supposed to help me, didn't find any useful information about allowed values.

Comment: Have a look at [Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working with mod_rewrite + mod_jk](http://serverfault.com/q/136428/5058)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally followed another way, in the .htaccess:

```
SetEnvIf Origin "^http(s)?://(.+\.)?example\.com$" AccessControlAllowOrigin=$0
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin %{AccessControlAllowOrigin}e env=AccessControlAllowOrigin
```

Works fine.
Special thanks to Gumbo.

Comment: you also need to set header. vary: origin. see w3c https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#resource-implementation

Answer (score -1):

```
\bhttps?:\/\/.+?example\.com\b
```

[DEMO](http://rubular.com/r/YyVd9QzJRM)